# JPA Query ElementCollection

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

(I've tried previous answers, to no avail)

I want to get all the A object which have sip = X.

```
public class A {

    @Id
    @ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)
    private UUID id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "a_sips")
    @Column(name = "sip_id")
    private Set<Long> sips;
}
```

I've tried:

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, UUID> {
    @Query("FROM A a JOIN a.sips s WHERE s = :sipId")
    Page<A> findAllBySip(@Param("sipId") Long sipId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

and got:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for
>   class com.models.A. Expected: class java.util.UUID, got class
>   java.lang.Long

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the code you tried to execute, and the complete and exact stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure if your query is correct or not, but anyway, a better one would be `select a from A a where :sipId member of a.sips`.

Comment: Could it be that the column in a_sips that is a foreign key to table A is typed long, rather than UUID?

Comment: JPQL starts with "SELECT {alias}". Any JPA reference doc would tell you that

Comment: @billy it is also valid to use the hibernate query language. however, jb member of clause would be the most apprpriate clause to use here.

Comment: Not if the question is not tagged as Hibernate it aint